# Removing styles from jQuery.validator after successful validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have the following code which adds custom css styles to my form when using the jQuery validation plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

        // Adds the red outline
        element.parent().addClass("error");

        // Adds the red cross
        element.siblings(".error_status").addClass('check');

        // Removes the default error
        element.removeClass("error");
        }       
    });

 $("#form").validate();

});
```

Which styles the following html for each element:

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="id-3"><span>Email address:</span><span class="mark">*</span>
    <input type="text" class="text required" id="id-3" name="email"/>
    <span class="error_status"></span>
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to subsequently remove the styles after a successful validation.

Comment: What do you mean with "remove the styles after a successful validation"? After a successful validation the data is sent to the server. Can you provide an example on jsFiddle.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use the `highlight` and `unhighlight` callbacks (documented [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)) instead of `errorPlacement`. This way, you won't have to manually remove the `error` class from the element:

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        var $element = $(element);
        // Add the red outline.
        $element.parent().addClass(errorClass);
        // Add the red cross.
        $element.siblings(".error_status").addClass("check");
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        var $element = $(element);
        // Remove the red cross.
        $element.siblings(".error_status").removeClass("check");
        // Remove the red outline.
        $element.parent().removeClass(errorClass);
    }
});
```

Comment: Excellent that fixed it. However it seemed that element wasn't an element object but just the html? I fixed this by putting $(element).sib... rather than just element.sib

Comment: You're right, the callbacks are indeed called with a DOM element and not a jQuery object. Answer updated accordingly, thank you for your feedback :)